# Audio balance messed up after reboot

Tags: sound, 22.04, system-settings

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, this happens with an external audio adapter (i-tec USB-C Dual Display Docking Station).

Sometimes after a reboot I only get sound from the right speaker. In the Sound Settings the slider is fully to the right. I have to move it back to the middle to get sound from both speakers. After the next or so reboot (it occurs randomly) it is at the right again (without me touching it).

The docking station is a huge annoyance in many ways, but I don't think that it can tamper with the Ubuntu settings. I actually can't remember if this happened with the internal speakers as well before I started to use the dock. Sorry for the missing info here.

What could be wrong here? How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!